# Reading RSS feed in Python

Tags: python, xml, rss

I am trying to obtain the first title.text from this RSS feed: https://www.mmafighting.com/rss/current. The feed is up to date and operational. However, when I use the following code, it appears the script is not finding any  tags. Running another code sample, it is also not finding any  tags.

I tried the following. I was expecting this to return the text of the first  that falls within the first  tag.

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree

rss_url = 'https://www.mmafighting.com/rss/current'
response = requests.get(rss_url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    rss_feed = response.text
    # parse the RSS feed using xml.etree.ElementTree
    root = ElementTree.fromstring(rss_feed)
    entries = root.findall(".//entry")
    if len(entries) > 0:
        title = entries[0].find("title")
        if title is not None:
            print(title.text)
        else:
            print("No title found in the first entry")
    else:
        print("No entry found in the RSS feed")
else:
    print("Failed to get RSS feed. Status code:", response.status_code)
```

the code returns "No entry found in the RSS feed"

Comment: hey @Dalej400, it's an easy fix, have u tried using bs4?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need module feedparser
install = **pip install feedparser**

then you need to write code like this

```
import feedparser

rss_url = 'https://www.mmafighting.com/rss/current'
feed = feedparser.parse(rss_url)

if feed.status == 200:
    for entry in feed.entries:
        print(entry.title)
        print(entry.link)
else:
    print("Failed to get RSS feed. Status code:", feed.status)
```

output from above code :

[image: output]

Comment: thank you, that output is exactly what I am looking for. however, when running the code you posted, I receive "AttributeError: object has no attribute 'status'.

Comment: troubleshooting with this script

if feed.bozo == 1:
    print("Failed to get RSS feed.")
    print("Error type:", type(feed.bozo_exception))
    print("Error message:", feed.bozo_exception)
else:
    for entry in feed.entries:
        print(entry.title)
        print(entry.link)



Output: 

Failed to get RSS feed.
Error type: <class 'urllib.error.URLError'>
Error message: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:992)>

Comment: @Dalej400 This error message suggests that there is an issue with the SSL certificate verification process when trying to retrieve the RSS feed. The message "certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate" means that the certificate provided by the server could not be verified against a trusted certificate authority. This could be due to a misconfiguration on the server, an out-of-date certificate, or an issue with your local certificate store.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely caused by the xml namespace, which is specified at the top of the feed element.

In the script you have used the findall method with the argument ".//entry" to find all the entry elements. However, since the feed uses the xml namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom", this path does not match any elements in the feed.

One way to handle this is by specifying the namespace when calling the findall method. You can do this by adding the namespace as a key-value pair in a dictionary and passing it as the second argument to the findall method.

```
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree

rss_url = 'https://www.mmafighting.com/rss/current'
response = requests.get(rss_url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    rss_feed = response.text
    # parse the RSS feed using xml.etree.ElementTree
    root = ElementTree.fromstring(rss_feed)
    ns = {'atom': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'}
    entries = root.findall('.//atom:entry', ns)
    # print(f"entries: {entries}")
    if len(entries) > 0:
    #    for entry in entries:
        # title = entry.find("atom:title", ns)
        title = entries[0].find("atom:title", ns)
        if title is not None:
            print(title.text)
        else:
            print("No title found in this entry")
    else:
        print("No entry found in the RSS feed")
else:
    print("Failed to get RSS feed. Status code:", response.status_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by using beautiful soup,

here the updated code:

```py
import requests
# from xml.etree import ElementTree
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


rss_url = 'https://www.mmafighting.com/rss/current'
response = requests.get(rss_url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    rss_feed = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(rss_feed, features="xml")
    entries = soup.find_all('title')
    if len(entries) > 0:
        title = entries[0]
        if title is not None:
            print(title.text)
        else:
            print("No title found in the first entry")
    else:
        print("No entry found in the RSS feed")
else:
    print("Failed to get RSS feed. Status code:", response.status_code)
```

variable `entries` is a list that contains all the titles, you can iterate on `entries` to get all the titles.

Output:
[image: Output of the code]

How to install Beautiful Soup?

Just run this command-
`pip install bs4`

Comment: I will consider this. Thank you!